# How to expose Linkerd dashboard via Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, linkerd

I have a 3 node K3s cluster with Linkerd and NGINX Ingress Controller. I installed Linkerd with a default configuration:

```
linkerd install | kubectl apply -f -
```

Then to install the NGINX Ingress Controller I used helm with a default configuration as well:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

I can access the Linkerd dashboard by calling `linkerd viz dashboard`, but I'd like to expose the dashboard with an Ingress definition. I modified the example yaml file from Linkerd's website located [here](https://linkerd.io/2.10/tasks/exposing-dashboard/#nginx), so that I could use a prefix path. In the end, my yaml file looked like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: web-ingress-auth
  namespace: linkerd-viz
data:
  auth: YWRtaW46JGFwcjEkbjdDdTZnSGwkRTQ3b2dmN0NPOE5SWWpFakJPa1dNLgoK
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: linkerd-viz
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:8084
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Origin "";
      proxy_hide_header l5d-remote-ip;
      proxy_hide_header l5d-server-id;      
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: web-ingress-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /linkerd
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            serviceName: web
            servicePort: 8084
```

For any of my other custom microservices, I can simply access them via the public IP address of my nginx ingress service. I can get this IP like this:

```
kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress" | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

When I try accessing the dashboard at http://EXPOSED_IP/linkerd, I am prompted to enter my username and password (both **admin** by default), but then I get a 404 not found error.

Does anybody know what could be the issue? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's never going to like the path. It needs to serve on the root of the url. So change path to '/' and it should work fine. I'm happy to try it out locally if that doesn't work.

Comment: This is correct. I'd only add that even using rewrite-target annotation won't help since there is no way to tell linkerd dashboard that it's running behind the proxy. If you (@Brent) want, you can create a feature request on [linkerd github issues](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues) to make it possible to tell the dashboard that it is running behind the proxy, or be able to set the base path.